# JQuery addClass not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen many post about this but none of them bring me a solution;

I have implemented a drag and drop functionality in my site.
When I drag above a valid container I add a class to it.

The html for the container;

```
<div id="boxL" class="boxL" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
```

Now when ondragover event is triggered it calls for this JavaScript

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var id = event.target.id;
       $(document).ready(function(e){ 
       $('#'+id).addClass('dotted');
    });
}
```

And the css class;

```
.dotted{
  border: 5px dotted #212121;  
}
```

Its working in every browser but not for firefox!?

Any clues?

Comment: Try this: `var id = ev.target.id;`

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you Sir.

Comment: "every browser" - being IE, Edge, and now Chrome ...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var obj = $('.boxL');

 obj.on('dragenter', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('dragenter');
 });
 obj.on('dragover', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 obj.on('drop', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('drop');
 });
 $(document).on('dragenter', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 $(document).on('dragover', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  obj.removeClass('dragenter');
 });
 $(document).on('drop', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
.boxL { width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#bababa; border:5px solid #333}
.dragenter{border: 5px dotted #212121;  }
.drop{border: 5px dotted red;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxL">
```